# Laravel. Get data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

How can i get data from pivot table directly (with Laravel)?

I have model \App\Model\Orders

```
class Orders extends Model
{
     public function related_orders()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Model\Orders::class,'related_orders','order_id','related_id');
     }
}
```

oK, i can get data from pivot table as

```
$order = \App\Model\Orders::find(1);

foreach ($order->related_orders as $related_order) {
    $related_order->pivot->related_id;
}
```

But, i need only related order id! I don't want retrieve all related orders for get one id field. It's irrationally.

Can you help me?

PS: I know how do it with sql query it's no problem. I wonder how to do this with Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do seems pretty simple if I'm understanding correctly. If you want an array of ID's for the related orders, just do this:

```
$relatedOrders = $order->related_orders->pluck('id');
```

Let me know if that's what you meant and if that gives the correct result, perhaps there's something more you're looking to do that I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Get a specific order (in this case, 1):

```
$order = \App\Model\Orders::find(1);
```

Get the related order for the above order:

```
$relatedOrders = $order->related_orders->first();
```

Get the ID (assuming your column is id)

```
return $relatedOrders->id;
```